# Plotting selective values in R above above a given value

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, subset

I have two columns of data in a data frame in R. I want to plot values from the 2nd column that are above a particular value say 'p'. And I also want to have the X axis as the first column i.e the values in column 1 corresponding to the values in column 2 that are above 'p'. I cant exactly find my way around this using the subset function. It only plots one column for me. Any help ?

Comment: You already have two good answers, but could you still provide a working example which demonstrates what is not working for you. This way we might be able to explain what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
df[df$col2 > threshold,]
```

to subset your data, or:

```
subset(df, col2 > threshold)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sample_data <- data.frame(v1 = rnorm(100), v2 = rnorm(100))
p <- 0.5
plot(sample_data[sample_data$v2 > p, ])
plot(subset(sample_data, v2 > p))
```